# Powershell how to concatenate with args

Tags: powershell

I just want to concatenate with args string but I get -System.Object[] in $test instead of "testapp" if args is app:

```
 function test {
   Write-Host $args;
   $test = -join("test",$args.ToString());
   Write-Host $test;
 }
```

Comment: Either `(@("test") + $args) -join ' '` to join with self-defined character or `-join (@("test") + $args)`. `@()` ensures the extra string 'test' is an array, then simply add the `$args` array to that and join the elements

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2):

```sh
function test {
    Write-Host $args
    $test = "test$args"
    Write-Host $test
}

test app
```

Output:

```text
app
testapp
```

String interpolation joins the array values using the space character by default.

To specify a custom separator string, use the `-join` Operator like this:

```sh
function test {
    Write-Host $args
    $argsJoined = $args -join ', '
    $test = "test $argsJoined"
    Write-Host $test
}

test 4 8 15
```

Output:

```text
4 8 15
test 4, 8, 15
```

---

**As for what you have tried:**

> ```
> $test = -join("test",$args.ToString());
> ```

`$args` is an array, whose `ToString()` method only returns the type name of the array.

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) pointed out in his helpful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346826/powershell-how-to-concatenate-with-args/72348248#comment127810116_72346826), you could make that work by using array concatenation:

```
$test = -join(@("test") + $args)
```

The [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#the-array-sub-expression-operator) `@` ensures that the `+` operator applies to an array, instead of the string `"test"`.

Slightly shorter variant:

```
$test = -join @("test"; $args)
```

Note the use of `;` to turn `$args` into a *sub-expression*, which effectively *unrolls* it.

In both cases the argument of the `-join` operator is a new array that is a combination of `"test"` and the elements of the `$args` array.